# React Not working on Android 4.4.2 web view browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React doesn't work in my Android phone. I don't think it my code error because even when the only thing I write is `<p>hello world </p>` it still doesn't show. After view it on chrome remote condole. It showed

```
Map is not defined
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I'm using react and react-dom 16.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Some older browsers do not support javascript newer features (such as `Map`).

An easy way to check if a feature exist in a browser is by using `typeof`. `typeof Map`, for instance, will return `undefined` if the browser doesn't support `Map`.

What can you do about it is to polyfills those features. A popular one is [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Comment: I use babel-env in my project do I still need the polyfill?

Comment: https://github.com/epsitec-sa/babel-env Are you talking about this package? Looking from the repo, it doesn't actually apply babel-polyfill into your code.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and when we added these polyfills that are recommend on React's website the problem was solved :) https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and connect `https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/` to your site