# ReactJS not working in WebView before Android API Level 23

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview

I'm making an Android app that consists mainly of WebViews and shows a React app. The Android app should support as far back as API level 16, but the React app only works at API level 23. The WebView is based on Chromium in Android 4.4, shouldn't it at least work from that version on?

I'm not getting any errors or feedback. 
I put a console log statement on the index page, and that is shown in Logcat.

How do i know what's unsupported or could there be a different problem?

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or feedback. The webview doesn't show anything. I put a console log statement in de index page, and that is shown in Logcat.

Comment: @Cool7 damn looks like I am getting errors: "Map is not defined", which makes it a duplicate of this question I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881966/react-not-working-on-android-4-4-2-web-view-browser